# onEdit(e) in Google Script - trying to put last edited date in cell and exclude this functionality on certain sheets (tabs)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a Google sheets script that enters the date of the last edit in a specific cell on all tabs except for the ones i specifically exclude.

My script currently looks like this, works, but does update on every tab instead of only the ones not specifically excluded.

```
function onEdit(e) { 
    if ((!e.value) &&
   (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetName() !== "cheese" || 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetName() !== "ham" ||
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetName() !== "toast" ||
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetName() !== "butter" ||
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetName() !== "popcicle" ||
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetName() !== "cake" ||
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetName() !== "meat"))
 {
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('B5').setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what you were doing with !e.value.

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) 
{ 
  var excluded=['cheese','ham','toast','butter','popcicle','cake','meat']
  if(excluded.indexOf(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName())>0)
  {
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('B5').setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm a newbie when it come to javascript so the "!e" was copied from a script example on googles forums.
Your code works but it still runs on pages supposed to be excluded. I will tinker more with it when I get off work.
Thanks.

Comment: Use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6) as a reference.

Comment: I got it working fine and dandy and have it inserting the email of the user who performed the edit as well.
Thank you kindly!